# Validation failed: Jobs is invalid (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following along with this series on YouTube, but now im stuck with this error when ever i try to post.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56GYV7Jj-uk&t=574s

Any fix for this issue im having with Rails?

https://github.com/justalever/job_board/issues/

Here's the error msg:

Validation failed: Jobs is invalid
create
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb, line 54

### And here's my jobs_controller.rb:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /jobs
  # GET /jobs.json
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  # GET /jobs/1
  # GET /jobs/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /jobs/new
  def new
    @job = current_user.jobs.build
  end

  # GET /jobs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /jobs
  # POST /jobs.json
  def create
    @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)

    token = params[:stripeToken]
    job_type = params[:job_type]
    job_title = params[:title]
    card_brand = params[:user][:card_brand]
    card_exp_month = params[:user][:card_exp_month]
    card_exp_year = params[:user][:card_exp_year]
    card_last4 = params[:user][:card_last4]

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => 30000,
      :currency => "usd",
      :description => job_type,
      :statement_descriptor => job_title,
      :source => token
      )

      current_user.stripe_id = charge.id
      current_user.card_brand = card_brand
      current_user.card_exp_month = card_exp_month
      current_user.card_exp_year = card_exp_year
      current_user.card_last4 = card_last4
      current_user.save!

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Your job listing was purchased successfully!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash.alert = e.message
      render action: :new
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update(job_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /jobs/1
  # DELETE /jobs/1.json
  def destroy
    @job.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_url, notice: 'Job was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_job
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :url, :job_type, :location, :job_author, :remote_ok, :apply_url, :avatar)
    end
end
```

Comment: The error is related to an ActiveRecord validation in your model.  Please post the code from app/models/job.rb

Comment: @sheepdog class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  JOB_TYPES = ["Full-time", "Part-time", "Contract", "Freelance"]
end

Comment: yes, i do, give me a sec

Comment: @sheepdog http://yayber.co.nf/

Comment: I think it has something to do with the gem i used: carrierwave and mini_magick, cause when i try to post a job listing without uploading an image, there is no error, but when i try to upload an img file, this error occurs

Comment: ok, thank you, i will try this as soon as i get back

Comment: Never mind that won't help you much. Try these two lines instead: `@job.valid?` and `Rails.logger.info(@job.errors.full_messages.join(', '))`

Comment: didn't work, same error, but again, the error only shows when i try to upload an image using carrierwave and mini_magick, if i dont upload any image, the job listing went through(no error)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that code is logging the error message to server log.  You can usually see it wherever you ran `rails server` or by checking `log/development.log` or `log/production.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `current_user.save!` is raising an error before you get a chance to try to save the job.  Try temporarily changing `current_user.save!` to `current_user.save`, then add error info to the flash: `flash.alert = @job.errrors.full_messages.join(', ')` )

```
  # POST /jobs
  # POST /jobs.json
  def create
    @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)

    token = params[:stripeToken]
    job_type = params[:job_type]
    job_title = params[:title]
    card_brand = params[:user][:card_brand]
    card_exp_month = params[:user][:card_exp_month]
    card_exp_year = params[:user][:card_exp_year]
    card_last4 = params[:user][:card_last4]

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => 30000,
      :currency => "usd",
      :description => job_type,
      :statement_descriptor => job_title,
      :source => token
      )

      current_user.stripe_id = charge.id
      current_user.card_brand = card_brand
      current_user.card_exp_month = card_exp_month
      current_user.card_exp_year = card_exp_year
      current_user.card_last4 = card_last4
      current_user.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Your job listing was purchased successfully!' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        flash.alert = @job.errrors.full_messages.join(', ')
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```